# Make a single array from multiple object in same value

Tags: javascript, express

I am facing a problem in express js. I have 2 object which data comes from DB for the same product code in different  product sale. After retrieve the data, I want  to make an object /array which will be a single array. My Sample Object which comes from db is like

```
 const preorder_data = [
  {
    region: "Rajshahi",
    area: "Bogra",
    house: "Mr Brothers",
    territory: "Bogra 1",
    point: "Bogura",
    skid: 20000007,
    dpid: 221,
    route: "18A",
    retailer_code: "RAJ-38-00526",
    volume: 4,
    value: 5840,
    date: "2022-01-30T18:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    region: "Rajshahi",
    area: "Bogra",
    house: "Mr Brothers",
    territory: "Bogra 1",
    point: "Bogura",
    skid: 20000003,
    dpid: 221,
    route: "18A",
    retailer_code: "RAJ-38-00526",
    volume: 5,
    value: 8952,
    date: "2022-01-30T18:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    region: "Rajshahi",
    area: "Bogra",
    house: "M/S Sons",
    territory: "Bogra 2",
    point: "Bogura",
    skid: 20000009,
    dpid: 221,
    route: "22B",
    retailer_code: "RAJ-39-85632",
    volume: 4,
    value: 5840,
    date: "2022-01-30T18:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    region: "Rajshahi",
    area: "Bogra",
    house: "M/S Sons",
    territory: "Bogra 2",
    point: "Bogura",
    skid: 20000005,
    dpid: 221,
    route: "22B",
    retailer_code: "RAJ-39-85632",
    volume: 5,
    value: 3965,
    date: "2022-01-30T18:00:00.000Z",
  },{
    region: "Rajshahi",
    area: "Bogra",
    house: "M/S Sons",
    territory: "Bogra 2",
    point: "Bogura",
    skid: 20000002,
    dpid: 221,
    route: "22B",
    retailer_code: "RAJ-39-85632",
    volume: 8,
    value: 13366,
    date: "2022-01-30T18:00:00.000Z",
  },
  
];
```

And the output which I wish like

```
    [
      {
        region: 'Rajshahi',
        area: 'Bogra',
        house: 'Mr Brothers',
        territory: 'Bogra 1',
        point: 'Bogura',
        dpid: 221,
        route: '18A',
        retailer_code: 'RAJ-38-00526',
        date: 2022-01-31
        sale_info :{
                skid:20000003
                volume:5,
                value:8952
              },
              { 
                skid:20000007
                volume:4,
                value:5840
              }
      },{
        region: "Rajshahi",
        area: "Bogra",
        house: "M/S Sons",
        territory: "Bogra 2",
        point: "Bogura",
        dpid: 221,
        route: "22B",
        retailer_code: "RAJ-39-85632",
        date: 2022-01-31
        sale_info :[{
                skid:20000002
                volume:8,
                value:13366
              },
              { 
                skid:20000005
                volume:5,
                value:3965
              },
              { 
                skid:20000009
                volume:4,
                value:5840
              }]
        },    
     ]
```

I have tried by the below code which doesnt work. Please help me. Here skid refers the product code.Thanks in advance.

```
var final_arr = []; 
    preorder_data.forEach(async (val, key) => {
        var temp_arr = [];         
           
        temp_arr.push(val.region);
        temp_arr.push(val.area);
        temp_arr.push(val.house);
        temp_arr.push(val.territory);
        temp_arr.push(val.point);
        temp_arr.push(val.route);
        temp_arr.push(val.retailer_code);       
      
        final_arr.push(temp_arr);
    });
```

Comment: What are you grouping by?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
// Initial data
const preorder_data = [
{
    region: 'Rajshahi',
    area: 'Bogra',
    house: 'Mr Brothers',
    territory: 'Bogra 1',
    point: 'Bogura',
    skid: 20000007,
    dpid: 221,
    route: '18A',
    retailer_code: 'RAJ-38-00526',
    volume: 4,
    value: 5840,
    date: '2022-01-30T18:00:00.000Z'
},
{
    region: 'Rajshahi',
    area: 'Bogra',
    house: 'Mr Brothers',
    territory: 'Bogra 1',
    point: 'Bogura',
    skid: 20000003,
    dpid: 221,
    route: '18A',
    retailer_code: 'RAJ-38-00526',
    volume: 5,
    value: 8952,
    date: '2022-01-30T18:00:00.000Z'
}];

// Get the "sales data" from each object in initial data array (skid, value, volume) and place it into a sales_data array
const sales_data = preorder_data.map((x) =>
{
    const { skid, value, volume } = x;
    return { skid, value, volume };
});

// Make the final, single object, which has the sales_data array
// We just grab all the keys of the first object in the initial data array, 
// filter out the sales related keys and attach the sales data to it
const final = { ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(preorder_data[0]).filter(([key]) => 
{
    return !key.includes('skid') && !key.includes('value') && !key.includes('volume')
})), sales_data };
```

Answer (score 0):

fist create array of your data like this

```
const preorder_data = [
  {
    region: "Rajshahi",
    area: "Bogra",
    house: "Mr Brothers",
    territory: "Bogra 1",
    point: "Bogura",
    skid: 20000007,
    dpid: 221,
    route: "18A",
    retailer_code: "RAJ-38-00526",
    volume: 4,
    value: 5840,
    date: "2022-01-30T18:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    region: "Rajshahi",
    area: "Bogra",
    house: "Mr Brothers",
    territory: "Bogra 1",
    point: "Bogura",
    skid: 20000003,
    dpid: 221,
    route: "18A",
    retailer_code: "RAJ-38-00526",
    volume: 5,
    value: 8952,
    date: "2022-01-30T18:00:00.000Z",
  },
];
```

then do like this

```
let dataArr = {};
let newData = preorder_data.map((data) => {
  dataArr = {
    ...dataArr,
    region: data.region,
    area: data.area,
    house: data.house,
    territory: data.territory,
    point: data.point,
    dpid: data.dpid,
    route: data.route,
    retailer_code: data.retailer_code,
    date: data.date,
  };
  return { skid: data.skid, value: data.value, volume: data.volume };
});
dataArr = { ...dataArr, newData };
```

Comment: Thank you so much Darshan. It works for a single retailer code. But when I have different retailer code, it give the result like,
  {
  region: 'Rajshahi',
  area: 'Bogra',
  house: 'Mr Brothers',
  territory: 'Bogra 1',
  point: 'Bogura',
  dpid: 221,
  route: '22A',
  retailer_code: 'RAJ-38-08839',
  date: '2022-01-30T18:00:00.000Z',
  newData: [
    { skid: 20000001, value: 204, volume: 2 },
    { skid: 20000001, value: 102, volume: 1 },
    { skid: 20000002, value: 204, volume: 1 }
  ]
}

Comment: ok so you want bifurcation by retailer code right ??? , any other key for this , so I can give you solution for that

Comment: yes bro, I have given the sample code for a single retailer code, but it must have multiple reatiler code.

Comment: Darshan , I have edited my question. Please check out. I have given 2 retailer code as a sample. But it will not be 2/3 retailers code. It must be multiple number of retailer code which comes from database raw query. For understanding , I have given 2 retailers data.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
const preorder_data = [
  {
    region: "Rajshahi",
    area: "Bogra",
    house: "Mr Brothers",
    territory: "Bogra 1",
    point: "Bogura",
    skid: 20000007,
    dpid: 221,
    route: "18A",
    retailer_code: "RAJ-38-00526",
    volume: 4,
    value: 5840,
    date: "2022-01-30T18:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    region: "Rajshahi",
    area: "Bogra",
    house: "Mr Brothers",
    territory: "Bogra 1",
    point: "Bogura",
    skid: 20000003,
    dpid: 221,
    route: "18A",
    retailer_code: "RAJ-38-00526",
    volume: 5,
    value: 8952,
    date: "2022-01-30T18:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    region: "Rajshahi",
    area: "Bogra",
    house: "Mr Brothers",
    territory: "Bogra 1",
    point: "Bogura",
    skid: 20000003,
    dpid: 221,
    route: "18A",
    retailer_code: "RAJ-38-00527",
    volume: 5,
    value: 8952,
    date: "2022-01-30T18:00:00.000Z",
  },
];

let tempArr = [];
let unique = preorder_data.map((data) => {
  let saleData = { skid: data.skid, value: data.value, volume: data.volume };
  let filterDataArr = tempArr.filter(
    (filterData) => filterData.retailer_code == data.retailer_code
  );
  if (filterDataArr && filterDataArr.length > 0) {
    filterDataArr[0].sale_info.push(saleData);
  } else {
    let sale_info = [];
    sale_info.push(saleData);
    let dataArr = {
      region: data.region,
      area: data.area,
      house: data.house,
      territory: data.territory,
      point: data.point,
      dpid: data.dpid,
      route: data.route,
      retailer_code: data.retailer_code,
      date: data.date,
      sale_info: sale_info,
    };
    tempArr.push(dataArr);
  }
});
```

in the tempArr you will get result

Comment: Thanks again bro.. In sale info object result return Object. Like  sale_info: [ [Object] ]. Another thing is ok.

Comment: yes because in console object in object are print like that way , for data check console array[index].sales_info you will get the data

Comment: how can i access data from the below object , while i need sales info data.{ region: 'Rajshahi', area: 'Bogra', house: 'Mr Brothers', territory: 'Bogra 1', point: 'Bogura', dpid: 221, route: '18A', retailer_code: 'RAJ-38-00526', date: '2022-01-30T18:00:00.000Z', sale_info: [ [Object], [Object] ] }

Comment: // console.log("tempArr=>", tempArr);
// console.log("tempArr=>", tempArr[0].sale_info);
// console.log("tempArr=>", tempArr[1].sale_info);
do this you will get the data in sale_info
& for access data you will always use loop

Comment: Thank you so much Darsan. I have got the everything.